# Test browser support for HTML5 elements and API's. Why does this work

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have chosen to avoid identifying the browser as unreliable and messy. Instead I am just testing for actual support of each of the elements or APIs my page uses. For testing audio support I have come up with this.

```
function testAudio()
    {
    if(window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext)
        {
        myAudio = new AudioContext();
        alert("Browser supports AudioContext");
        }
    else
        {
        if(window.Audio = window.Audio)
            {
            myAudio = new Audio();
            alert("Browser supports Audio Element");
            }
        else {alert("This browser does not support AudioContext or Audio Element");}
        }
    }
```

Works like a charm. Current browsers return true for AudioContext, IE11 returns true only for Audio() and IE 8 returns false for both. But WHY?

In the case of true I am assigning an object to an object property of the window object. Is there an AudioContext and Audio element property of the window object? Or is the browser returning true for an assignment to an object that could exist but doesn't?

In the case of false I am assigning an object that the browser doesn't recognize to a property of the window object that doesn't exist. Why does it return false instead of throwing an error, null or undefined? And why would this return false while

```
if(myAudio = new AudioContext()) or if(myAudio = new Audio()) throw errors?
```

Comment: According to caniuse.com, Audio is supported as of IE11 and AudioContext as of Edge. What else would you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 does not fully support HTML5, and that includes the `Audio` API. If you want IE8 support you'll need to include [a polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills).

When you try to instantiate a new object using a non-existent object prototype (i.e. `new AudioContext()`) you should expect an error. But `if (window.AudioContext)` is merely checking for the existence of the property--it is not calling a function, so there is no error.

The issue you're facing here is that this is an odd way to check if the browser supports the API in question.

For example,

```
if (window.Audio = window.Audio)
```

in IE8 is going to be the same as this:

```
if (window.Audio = undefined)
```

which, if you remove the assignment, can be reduced to this:

```
if (undefined)
```

which is falsy, meaning that it's going to have the same result as this:

```
if (false)
```

so you'll never get into that block.

Comment: You are right. The assignment is irrelevant. I was following the syntax from MDN "if(window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)" but this is redundant. if(window.AudioContext) and if(window.Audio) work just fine and make more sense.